# Input masking not working in react DatePicker with validation

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am using `ReduxForm` and  `DatePicker` in my code. For the `Datepicker` I am using input masking to display the date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import MaskedInput from 'react-text-mask'
import createAutoCorrectedDatePipe from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createAutoCorrectedDatePipe'
import moment from 'moment';
import _ from 'lodash';


const autoCorrectedDatePipe = createAutoCorrectedDatePipe('mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM')
class DashboardAddPendingPaymentStep1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

     renderDatePicker = ({ input:{value, onChange}, disabled, label, title, Required, meta: { touched, error } }) => (      
        <div title={title}>
            <div className={touched && error ? 'add-list_key alert' : 'add-list_key'}>
                {label}
                {Required && <span className="add-list_required"> *</span>}
            </div>
            <div className="add-list_value" style={{ 'minWidth': 230, 'maxWidth': 230 }}>
                <DatePicker
                    {...input} 
                    dateForm="MM/DD/YYYY"
                    selected={value ? moment(value) : null}
                    minDate={moment().subtract(10, 'years').startOf('year')}
                    maxDate={moment().endOf('year')}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    customInput={
                        <MaskedInput
                            pipe={autoCorrectedDatePipe}
                            mask={[/\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
                            keepCharPositions= {true}
                            guide = {true}
                        />

                    }
                />
                {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
            </div>
        </div>
    ); 






    validateOnSubmit = (value, additionalFormData, patientId, onHideSideListMenu) => {
        const errors = {};

        const requiredFields = ['PaymentDate'];
        requiredFields.forEach(field => {
            if (!value[field]) {
                errors[field] = '*';
            }
        });
        if (_.isEmpty(errors)) {
            this.props.onAddPendingPayment(_.extend(additionalFormData, value), patientId, onHideSideListMenu);
        } else {
            let mandatory = '';
            if (errors.PaymentDate) {
                mandatory = mandatory + '\n Date Captured';
            }
            notifications.showWarning('Following are requested fields:\n ' + mandatory, 'RequestedField');
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit, onHideSideListMenu } = this.props;

        const additionalFormData = {

            PaymentDate: '',

        };

        return (
            <form className="side-list-content add-payment" onSubmit={handleSubmit(value => this.validateOnSubmit(value, additionalFormData, parseInt(patientId), onHideSideListMenu))}>
                <ul >
                    <li >
                        <Field
                            name="PaymentDate"
                            component={this.renderDatePicker}
                            type="text"
                            label="Date Captured"
                            Required={true}
                            title="Date Captured Required"
                        />
                    </li>

            </form>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {

        }
    };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {


};

DashboardAddPendingPaymentStep1 = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(DashboardAddPendingPaymentStep1);

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'addPendingPaymentMenu'
})(DashboardAddPendingPaymentStep1);
```

Now I am getting this error,

1. > Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined
2. > Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
   >   string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
   >   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
   >   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
   >   default and named imports.

What might be the reason I am getting this error? How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

For error 1, you destructure your `input` prop into `value` and `onChange`, but then try to spread it into your `DatePicker` component, where at that point it is `undefined`.

For error 2, not so sure there... is there a more detailed error description, line number, call stack, etc, that you can provide?

Also, I don't know if it is perhaps just a copy/paste error, but you seem to also have an extra closing curly boy (`}`) in your `mapDispatchToProps` function.